# How to loop through files inside AWS S3 bucket in angular?

Tags: amazon-s3, angular16

I am trying to view all files in a specific folder inside my S3 bucket.

I made the connection:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    const config = {
      bucketName: 'angular-upload-files-2023-2024',
      dirName: '/properties2023/',
      region: 'ap-south-1',
      accessKeyId: environment.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: environment.secretAccessKey,
      s3Url: 'https://angular-upload-files-2023-2024.s3.amazonaws.com/'
  }
  
  const S3CustomClient = new AWSS3UploadAsh(config);
```

Now how to use this information to loop through files inside the directory "properties2023"?